# How does the forEach callback work behind the scenes in javascript? Is there a yield statement?

Tags: javascript

In javascript, I realize that the callback function is passed each element of the collection in a forEach method call, but how does it have access to it? In Ruby, we yield to the block.

```
def calculation(a, b)
  yield(a, b)
end

puts calculation(5, 6) { |a, b| a + b } # addition
puts calculation(5, 6) { |a, b| a - b } # subtraction
```

But in Javascript, how does the function get passed each element of the array? What's going on behind the scenes with the built in forEach function?

```
fruits.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
  console.log(item, index);
});
```

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill

Comment: ?? It just does exactly the same thing as you'd do with a `for` loop.

Comment: That's an implementation detail of whichever specific JavaScript compiler you want to talk about (and irrelevant to just about anyone writing JavaScript as opposed to JavaScript compilers).

Comment: Of course not. `forEach` is introduced in ECMAScript 5, while `yield` is in ECMAScript 6. So how could `forEach` be implemented with `yield`? Read the language spec, it's much better than guess.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's not that hard to implement more easily than its done [in the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill):

```
function forEach(fn) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) { // 'this' is the array, of course
        fn(this[i], i, this);
    }
}
```

<sub>I've also removed `thisArg` for simplicity's sake</sub>

The actual implementations do more checking and are more robust, but this illustrates the idea, I think. I can imagine it being implemented natively, as well.